# How to convert arrow Function to ES5 function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this arrow function in react:

```
const Welcome = ({subject, description}) => (
<div>
  <Person title={`Welcome ${subject}`}></Person>
  <Profile description={description}></Profile>
</div>
)
```

and I would like to convert to an es5 function but I am not able to get it to work:

```
var Welcome = function(subject,description) {
   return(
     <Person title="Welcome ".concat(subject)/>
     <Profile description=(description)/>
   );
};
```

How should I go about it? Thanks

Comment: You somehow lost the `<div>`. And you changed the object destructuring parameter into two separate parameters. And broke the JSX parameter syntax?

Comment: "*I would like to convert to an es5 function*" - why? And why not just use a transpiler for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do following steps:

1. wrap the 2 adjacent JSX elements with a common parent element.
2. wrap `{ }` around `'Welcome'.concat(subject)` and `description`.
3. destructure the function parameter.

```
var Welcome = function({subject, description}) {
   return(
     <div>
        <Person title={ 'Welcome'.concat(subject) }/>
        <Profile description={description}/>
     </div>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Welcome = function(subject,description) {
   return(
     <div>
        <Person title={"Welcome ".concat(subject)}/>
        <Profile description={description}/>
    </div>
   );
};
```

try this bro

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the destructuring in the params and also fogot to wrap the the html content under one parent tag

```
var Welcome = function({subject,description}) {
   return(
     <div>
        <Person title="Welcome ".concat(subject)/>
        <Profile description=(description)/>
    </div>
   );
};
```